# PASAR VALOR POR AJAX EN UN DATATABLE

Tags: javascript, mysql, ajax, nodejs

Tengo el siguiente código, donde estoy intentado pasar un valor a mi router por medio de AJAX en un DataTable.

```
   let id_contribuyente = $("#id_contribuyente").val()
                var table = $('#id_pagos').DataTable({
                    "ajax": {
                        "type": "POST",
                        "crossDomain": true,
                        "dataType": 'json',
                        "url": "/obtener-tramites-contribuyente?",
                        "data": {id_contribuyente:id_contribuyente},
                        "contentType": "application/jsonp"
                    }
```

En el router tengo lo siguiente, donde no me toma el valor enviado, no tengo experiencia usando Ajax y por lo mismo no identifico que estoy haciendo mal.

```
router.post("/obtener-tramites-contribuyente", authController.isAuthenticated, (req, res, results) => {
  const id_contribuyente = req.body.id_contribuyente;
conexion.query(`SELECT * FROM ticket t LEFT JOIN tramites r on t.id_tramites = r.id_tramites WHERE id_contribuyente = "${id_contribuyente}"`,
```

Comment: Agrega un **beforsend y error** a la petición Ajax en principio, con eso verifica si se manda la petición u ocurre algún error

Comment: @AntonioGalicia lo he colocado. En la consola del navegador me manda lo siguiente. ncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length').

Comment: No se comprende bien tu pregunta, si puedes reestructurarla especificando bien que es lo que quieres, mas aparte agregas todo tu código, con eso mas personas podríamos ayudarte.